# SegFault when using LSA_STRING

Tags: c++, windows, segmentation-fault

I want to use LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage() to get the Authentication Package for kerberos.
he [Windows docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntsecapi/nf-ntsecapi-lsalookupauthenticationpackage) tell me that it takes a PHandle which i called lsaHandle, a PLSA_STRING which i called packageNamePointer, and PULONG which I called auth package. I wrote it like this:

```
    LSA_STRING packageName;
    LPSTR tempPkgName = const_cast<LPSTR>("ker-beros");
    packageName.Length = static_cast<USHORT>(strlen(tempPkgName));
    packageName.MaximumLength = packageName.Length+1;
    packageName.Buffer = tempPkgName;

    PLSA_STRING packageNamePointer = &packageName;

    PULONG authPackage;

    errorCode = LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage(lsaHandle, packageNamePointer, authPackage);
    if(errorCode != SCESTATUS_SUCCESS){
        std::cout << LsaNtStatusToWinError(errorCode) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
```

However I always get a SegFault when calling LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage. I belive it has to do with the PLSA_STRING, as I had a similar problem when, calling LsaRegisterLogonProcess.

A gdb backtrace only gives me this:

#0  0x00007fff641f28f4 in SspiCli!LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sspicli.dll

#1  0x00007ff774f514fe in main () at C:/Users/user/Documents/folder/folder/folder/temp.cpp:38

I tried finding a sspicli.lib to link to, in order to get a better backtrace (if that would even help), but sadly couldn't find anything.

So what I am asking is: Why this code throws a segfault when calling LsaLookup and how would I prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what caused the problem, was the

```
PULONG authPackage;
```

This is a Pointer to an ULONG, so when I gave it to the method it had an unitialized pointer which caused the segfault. After changing the code to

```
ULONG authPackage;

errorCode = LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage(lsaHandle, packageNamePointer, &authPackage);
```

It all worked fine